# Serialize Array of Vector2 with Json.NET

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, json.net

I am trying to use Json.NET on Unity to serialize a class.
The class *Polygon* contains an *Array* of *Vector2* but i only want to serialize the x and y variables of Vector2 class, that's why I'm using the JsonConverter attribute.

**Sample class:**

```
public class Polygon
{
    public int count { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(Vector2Converter[]))]
    public Vector2[] points { get; set; }
}
```

It gives me this error at runtime:

> MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Default constructor not
>   found...ctor() of
>   JsonDotNet.Extras.CustomConverters.Vector2Converter[]

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[JsonConverter]` attribute takes the type of a converter, not the type of an array of converters.  If your converter is designed to handle the serialization of the entire array, then you need to specify it like this:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(Vector2Converter))]
    public Vector2[] points { get; set; }
```

If your converter is designed to serialize the individual items in the array, you need to use this syntax instead:

```
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType=typeof(Vector2Converter))]
    public Vector2[] points { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks Brian for the help